# Accessing HTML form element inside a Django template {% url %}

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I have a Django HTML template with `<form method="get" action="{% url 'handler_name' parameter %}">`. I wanted to replace the `parameter` with a form field's value. Does Django has any provisions for that?

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^sample-endpoint/$', view_function_1, name='endpoint1'),
url(r'^sample-endpoint/(\d+)/$', view_function_1, name='endpoint2'),
...
```

The first one `sample-endpoint/` is hit when the page loads for the first time. The page has an input (a number). On selecting a number, and clicking a button, the second one, say `sample-endpoint/1/` gets called and the same page gets rendered with some additional data.

**catalog.html**

```
<form id='get-list' name='get_list_form' method='get' 
      action='{% url "endpoint2" placeholder %}'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select id='select-catalog-id' name='catalog_id'>
        <option value='1'>Foo</option>
        <option value='2'>Bar</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I don't want to fetch the value on the server side in `views.py` using request.GET['catalog_id']. I feel having two URLs looks clean. And moreover, both URLs are for GET request.

My objective is to use the value of selected item in the dropdown (1 or 2, in this case) instead of `placeholder` in the form action. Is it provided out of the box in Django? Or some custom JavaScript?

Comment: This isn't anything that Django could possibly do. The `{% url %}` tag is resolved at render time, well before the user could select the value. You would have to write some JS.

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
{% if form.field.value %} value="{{ form.field.value }}" {% endif %} placeholder="{{ description }}"
```

Comment: I know this is not the answer shar was looking for, and it does not help him at all. BUT, it is the answer I was looking for when I found this post.  I thought if someone else uses the same search terms I did, and comes to this post, they will at least find my solution on here without looking hopelessly elsewhere.